# Showing series converge by comparison

Tags: convergence-divergence

Show that the following series diverges $$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \sin{\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}.$$

We do this by the comparison test. Let $a_{n} = \sin{\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}$
 Now the only test I can really apply here in my opinion is the comparison test however i'm not really sure what to compare this to. I want to find some $b_{n}<a_{n}$ and show that this $b_{n}$ diverges.

Comment: Use $\displaystyle \sin x \ge x - \frac{x^2}{3!}$

Comment: Of course! thanks.

Comment: No need to be so precise. $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}{\sin x\over x}=1$; so, for $n$ large enough, we have $ \sin(1/n)>\cdot(1/2){1\over n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $\sin{x}\ge x-\frac{x^{3}}{3!}$. Thus $$\sin{\frac{1}{n}}\ge \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{6n^{3}}.$$

Let $b_{n}=1/n-1/(6n^{3})$. Note $\sum b_{n}$ diverges and $b_{n}\le a_{n}$ thus $\sum a_{n}$ diverges by the comparison test.

Comment: Why is the first inequality true? Not only using the Taylor series for $\;\sin x\;$ here could be seen as an overkill, but how would this help you to prove the inequality?